# Wildfly not responding to REST services

Tags: java, docker, rest, kubernetes, wildfly

I have a Wildfly 26 application server running inside a Kubernetes pod. It's configured to support REST JAX-RS:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplicationConfig extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

I tested from a VM connected to Kubernetes with `curl`:

```
curl -X  POST 201.119.108.16:8080/visualcode/rest/getbropr
```

I set the console with DEBUG level and I see this:

> 21:56:10,151 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-1) Matched
> prefix path /visualcode for path /visualcode/rest/getbropr

That means that Wildfly is receiving the request. But in `curl` response I get:

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</body></html>
```

When I run this application in my Windows dev environment, `curl` runs fine. So the application should not be the problem.

This is the Java service:

```
@POST
@Path("/getbropr")
public Response getBrowserProperties() {
    BrowserProperties bp = bean.getBrowserProperties();
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("props", bp);
    map.put(Constant.Key.Ret, Constant.Code.Success);
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = om.writeValueAsString(map);
    return Response.ok(json).build();
}
```

Since I get the `curl` response, I would discard any routing issues in the middle.

How to fix this?

Comment: Is the context name correct? There should be a log message that indicates the context name for your deployment.

Comment: What do you call the context name?

Comment: Don't you have a `@Path` on the class containing the `getBrowserProperties()` method ? If so, the invoked url should be '.../visualcode/rest/path/getbropr'

Comment: You should see a log message similar to this `WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/contacts' for server 'default-server'`. In this example "/contacts" is the context name. Given your URL yours should be "visualcode".

Comment: @TacheDeChoco the `@Path` at the class level is "/" so the URL is /visualcode/rest/getbropr

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Yes, I see this `WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/visualcode' for server 'default-server'`

Comment: Now I see this after the message above: `17:47:38,239 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005007: Request was not fully consumed`

Comment: Interesting, that almost seems like an issue with k8s maybe closing the connection. That is definitely a guess though. One thing that might give you more information would be to add debug logging for org.jboss.resteasy as well.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins could this be a security issue?

Comment: It's really tough to say. While I've used k8s, I can't claim to be an expert at it :) I'd need to have some kind of reproducer to see what is happening, which I'm guessing isn't easy to share.